# react-hook-form + yup: show error when dependent inputs cause invalidity

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

Two date inputs - start must always come before end - and therefore, when one or the other causes it to be erroneous the message can be the same and shown once, i.e. "End cannot come before start."

```
const requiredDateError = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
const dateOrderError = 'date-order-error';

const dateRangeSchema = Yup.object({
  range: Yup.string().required(),
  startDate: Yup.string().when('range', {
    is: ranges.BETWEEN_DATES,
    then: (schema) => Yup.date().required(requiredDateError).max(Yup.ref('endDate'), dateOrderError)
  }),
  endDate: Yup.string().when('range', {
    is: ranges.BETWEEN_DATES,
    then: (schema) =>
      Yup.date().required(requiredDateError).min(Yup.ref('startDate'), dateOrderError)
  })
});
```

And, then the two controllers (just showing one as the difference is only the name start vs. end date):

```
<Controller
  control={form.control}
  name="endDate"
  render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value }, fieldState: { error, invalid } }) => (
    <TextField
      aria-label="To"
      aria-multiline="false"
      aria-placeholder="To"
      hasError={invalid}
      helperText={error?.message}
      inputProps={{
        style: { textTransform: 'uppercase' }
      }}
      maxlength={10}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      onChange={onChange}
      inputRef={endDateRef}
      role="textbox"
      type="date"
      value={value}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

Now, if the error is "date-order-error" (setup like this for future i18 support) I don't want to show the error under either component, individually, but rather a single spot to show one singular error. I've tried everything I can think of so here I am on SO. I feel like this should not be a special case, but something somebody else has needed to implement. Any help appreciated!